# Order Core Data Entities by different attributes but on the same level

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an entity called `Contact` with multiple attributes, including `givenName`, `organizationName` and `familyName`. I want to order them by `givenName` and then `familyName`. However, some entities may not have `givenName` or `familyName` but have `organizationName`. When sorting the `Contacts` I want to order the entities as `organizationName` and `givenName` where the same attribute, e.g. use organizationName when givenName is not available.

Currently I have:

```
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Contact> = Contact.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "givenName", ascending: true),
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "organizationName", ascending: true),
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "familyName", ascending: true)
        ]
```

I would write something similar like:

```
order by IS_EMPTY(IS_EMPTY(givenName, lastName), organizationName) ASC
```

How can I express that with Swift and Core Data?

Answer (score 0):

The more customization you need the more code you have to write.

`NSSortDescriptor` provides an initializer for a custom comparator, something like this

```
let myComparator : (Any, Any) -> ComparisonResult = { lhs, rhs in
    let lhs = lhs as! Contact
    let rhs = rhs as! Contact
    if !lhs.givenName.isEmpty { return lhs.givenName.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(rhs.givenName) }
    if !lhs.organizationName.isEmpty { return lhs.organizationName.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(rhs.organizationName) }
    return lhs.familyName.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(rhs.familyName)
}

let mySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: nil, ascending: true, comparator: myComparator)
```